# Gradle build fail with java 1.8, build tool 2.2.0-alpha4, enable jackOptions

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm building android project with gradle config below:
Android Studio 2.1.2

Project gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha4'
}
```

App gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<my_app_id>"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

The app always build failed with error:

```
2016-06-26 22:26:52,282 [1868500]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Cause: com/android/build/gradle/internal/model/DefaultAndroidProject : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cause: com/android/build/gradle/internal/model/DefaultAndroidProject : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:457)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:158)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:350)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:373)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:339)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:230)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:500)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
2016-06-26 22:26:52,282 [1868500]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -  
2016-06-26 22:26:52,282 [1868500]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - Cause: com/android/build/gradle/internal/model/DefaultAndroidProject : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2016-06-26 22:26:52,283 [1868501]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle for project '' failed: Cause: com/android/build/gradle/internal/model/DefaultAndroidProject : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Can someone point me in the right way on how to solve this issue?, Please help me out!

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

`Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` means you are using the wrong version of JDK. You will have to update your JDK to version 8, as you are setting your JAVA language version to 1.8.

Download JDK 8 from Oracle:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: I'm currently using Java 1.8 for Android Studio, I also have java 1.8 for JAVA_HOME variable.

Comment: you will also have to set JDK path in your module setting in Android Studio.
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem, it can be solved by following two steps:

Step 1: Download Java 8.
Step 2: Update Android Studio to the latest version 2.2.